# $wpdb -> changing multiple INSERT queries into a single query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have two tables:

1. Central_Address
   Address_ID - PK and Auto Increment
2. Central_Class_Location
   Central_Location_ID - PK and Auto Increment
   Address_ID_FK - Foreign key referencing Address_ID

I was able to use phpmyadmin to insert data in both tables, including the foreign key:

```
INSERT INTO Central_Address (Address_ID) VALUES ('');

INSERT INTO Central_Class_Location (Central_Location_ID, Address_ID) VALUES ('', LAST_INSERT_ID());
```

However, when I try to use Wordpress's $wpdb, it adds to Central_Address, but not Central_Class_Location

```
$wpdb->query("INSERT INTO Central_Address (Address_ID) VALUES ('');

INSERT INTO Central_Class_Location (Central_Location_ID, Address_ID) VALUES ('', LAST_INSERT_ID());");
```

Has anyone ever been able to make foreign keys with $wpdb?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to insert in Central_Address from wordpress method which is as follows

**1)** Insert Central_Address

```
$table = $wpdb->prefix.'Central_Address';
$data = array('column1' => 'data one', 'column2' => 123);
$format = array('%s','%d');
$wpdb->insert($table,$data,$format);
```

**2)** after then get database last inserted id using $wpdb->insert_id and run to insert second table query

```
$last_address_id = $wpdb->insert_id;

$central_class_location_table = $wpdb->prefix.'Central_Class_Location';
$data = array('Address_ID' => $last_address_id, 'column2' => 123);
$format = array('%d','%d');

$wpdb->insert($central_class_location_table, $data, $format);
```

I think it may have helped you